# Add columns in SharePoint list error with special characters

Tags: sharepoint-server, jsom

It throws error when I try to create and add column in list which contains special characters such as '&'.

I tried following:

DisplayName="a&b" Name="a&b"           --------  throws error

DisplayName="a&amp ;b" Name="a&amp ;b"   --------  throws error (remove space before';')

DisplayName="a&amp ;b" Name="a_x0026_b" -------- works fine (remove space before';')

Do I really need to convert special characters to their respective special codes
for example '&' to '*x0026*' ?

Is there any official document saying that ?

```
function addFields() {

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
        //Getting reference to the list
        oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List1');


        var f2 = clientContext.castTo(
                    oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Type="Choice"  DisplayName="a&amp;b" Name="a&amp;b" />', true, 
                    SP.AddFieldOptions.addToDefaultContentType),
                    SP.FieldChoice);
        var choices = Array("Approved", "Rejected", "Progress");
        f2.set_choices(choices);
        f2.update();

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
            );
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert("List Field Updated");
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }


addFields()
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/905231/information-about-the-characters-that-you-cannot-use-in-site-names,-fo

Comment: And yes, you need to convert the file characters.

Comment: I have requirement that '&' must be supported in list's column name at-least in display name

Comment: As long as you encode the internal column name (as long as it is not reserved by SharePoint), you should be able to set the display name to anything you want.